# Kivy MDToolBar right_action_items: Can't change Screens

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, toolbar, kivy-language

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to use the MDToolBar `right_action_items:` in kv to change screens. I know that with a button `on_release:` I can add a simple `app.root.current = 'analyzer'` (I defined my screen as 'analyzer' and 'main').

Yet you can't add this code to a `right_action_items: Lambda x: app.root.current = 'analyzer'` in kv.
So I tried adding a function in python that would do this for me inside my `Manager(ScreenManager)` -->

```
def change_screen(self, inst):
    Manager.current = f'{inst.ids.main.text}'
```

But it doesn't work... I'm lost, confused, afraid... help. me. please...

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd import *

from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import sys
import json
import requests


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    def change_screen(self, inst):
        Manager.current = f'{inst.ids.main.text}'

class Main(Screen):
    """main application goes here"""
    def close_dialog(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def show_data(self):
        message = """
        Think of Probably Knot (PK) as a study
        guide of sorts. Helping the user guide
        himself.

        This little program was designed to help
        re-think ones sentences and therefore 
        find new solutions. By changing ones
        perception, things can become more clear
        where once they were misunderstood.

        PK re-shuffle a word from an input
        sentence to help rephrase ones 
        orignal sentence. To better
        understand problems and ideas by
        changing the angle of perception
        with more elegant solutions.
        """
        close = MDIconButton(icon="close-circle", on_release=self.close_dialog)
        #more = MDIconButton(icon="more")
        self.dialog = MDDialog(title="Probably Knot Helper", text=message,
                         size_hint=(0.8, 1), buttons=[close])
        self.dialog.open()


class Analyzer(Screen):
    def analyze(self, main): # main is pointing to ---> Main().show_data()
        """Analyse data with PyDictionary"""

        sent = main.ids.sentence.text.lower()
        wrd = main.ids.word.text.lower()
        print(sent, wrd)

        # Definition Section #
        dictionary = PyDictionary()
        define_wrd = dictionary.meaning(wrd)

        if wrd != '' and sent != '':
            API_KEY = 'a701e74e453ee6695e450310340401f5'
            URL = f'http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/{API_KEY}/{wrd}/json'

            if wrd not in sent:
                print("i made it")
                error = MDDialog(title="Error", text=f"Word: '{wrd}' is not in\n\n'{sent}'")
                error.open()
            else:
                r = requests.get(URL) # get's url json file
                j = json.loads(r.text) # loads json into 'j' as a dict

                if type(j) == dict: # check is 'j' variable is coming in as a Dict holds the new sentences new = f"{result}\n"
                    final_set = set()
                    try:
                        for w in j['adjective']['syn']:
                            final_set.add(w)
                    except KeyError:
                        print(f'Adjective for "{wrd}" is not found.')
                    try:
                        for w in j['noun']['syn']:
                            final_set.add(w)
                    except KeyError:
                        print(f'Noun for "{wrd}" is not found.') 
                    try:
                        for w in j['verb']['syn']:
                            final_set.add(w)
                    except KeyError:
                        print(f'Verb for "{wrd}" is not found.')
                    item = TwoLineListItem(text=f"Original: {sent}", secondary_text=f"{wrd}")
                    self.ids.container.add_widget(item)
                    for word in final_set:
                        item = TwoLineListItem(text=f"{sent.replace(wrd, word)}", secondary_text=f"{word}")
                        self.ids.container.add_widget(item)
                    # try:
                    #     for num, w in enumerate(j['adjective']['syn'], 1):
                    #         item = OneLineListItem(text=f"{num}: {sent.replace(wrd, w)}\n")
                    #         self.ids.container.add_widget(item)
                    # except KeyError:
                    #     print(f'Adjective for "{wrd}" is not found.')
                    # try:
                    #     for num, w in enumerate(j['noun']['syn'], 1):
                    #         item = OneLineListItem(text=f"{num}: {sent.replace(wrd, w)}\n")
                    #         self.ids.container.add_widget(item)
                    # except KeyError:
                    #     print(f'Noun for "{wrd}" is not found.') 
                    # try:
                    #     for num, w in enumerate(j['verb']['syn'], 1):
                    #         item = OneLineListItem(text=f"{num}: {sent.replace(wrd, w)}\n")
                    #         self.ids.container.add_widget(item)
                    # except KeyError:
                    #     print(f'Verb for "{wrd}" is not found.')


class ProbablyKnotApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Amber"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"

        return Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ProbablyKnotApp().run()
```

kv

```
<Manager>:
    Main:
        id: main
        name: 'main'
    Analyzer:
        id: analyze
        name: 'analyzer'


<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: "Probably Knot v3"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            right_action_items: [["help-circle-outline", lambda x: app.root.get_screen('main').show_data()]]
        MDFloatLayout:
            MDTextField:
                id: sentence
                icon_right: "book-open-outline"
                icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color

                hint_text: "Enter Sentence"
                helper_text: "Write a problem statement to analyze"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                multiline: False
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: root.width - dp(20)
            MDTextField:
                id: word
                icon_right: "lead-pencil"
                icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color

                hint_text: "Enter Word"
                helper_text: "Write ONE word from the above sentence"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                multiline: False
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: root.width - dp(20)
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "brain"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
                user_font_size: 64
                on_press: app.root.get_screen('analyzer').analyze(root)
                on_release: app.root.current = 'analyzer'

            # MDRectangleFlatButton:
            #     text: "help"
            #     pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.75, 'center_y': .1}
            #     on_release: app.root.get_screen('main').show_data()


<Analyzer>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: "Probably Knot v3"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
            right_action_items: [["backburger", lambda x: main.change_screen(root)], ["help-circle-outline", lambda x: app.root.get_screen('main').show_data()]]
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: container
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having the same problem, I didn't find the perfect solution, but I found a way to remedy it.

In place of the `right_action_items` I used `MDFloatActionButton` inside the `MDToolbar` to look like this:

```
MDToolbar:
    title: 'Settings'
    elevation: 10

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: 'keyboard-backspace'
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        elevation: 0
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
       enter code here on_release: root.ids.screen_manager.current = 'Home'
```

Comment: Thank you, glad to know I'm not crazy!! I'll give this a try :) Valeu!

Comment: It worked! :) The only thing is now the backspace gives me a weird black circle outline around my icon once I press it. Have you encountered this?

Comment: Actually just figured out ```MDIconButton``` inside my ```MDToolBar``` seems to work better. No circle shadow (which I think came from it's ```elevation:``` properties in the ```MDFloatingActionButton```. Thanks again, you helped me see outside the box :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jacques answer. it works on my app.
I also found this solution in KivyMD
https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/213#issuecomment-598703010
my code:

```py
# .kv file
MDToolbar:
    type: "bottom"
    right_action_items: [["clock", lambda x : app.set_screen('ss')]]
    # 'ss' is the Screen name.
           
# .py file class Main(MDApp):
def set_screen(self, screen_name):
        self.root.current = screen_name
```